# patch creation for asp.net web application

Tags: c#, installation, patch

I have a web application deployed at client Intra net using websetup project and now i want that any change or update in the source application should be provided as a small release to the client which the client will install using the deployed application and the changes will be reflected rather than the whole application re deployed. Also the deployed patch would be roll back if it is creating problem.

I need to ask what would be the best and easy way to create a patch to fulfill my requirements discussed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum you will have to install is: replace dlls that have changed, replace markup (apsx/ascx) that has changed.  However it is rather pointless as it really doesn't save you very much in most cases.  The only time I ever do it is if i only have remote access and it is slow and the site is large. It saves on the amount of data to transfer.